# Close expanding search bar not closeing back down

Tags: javascript, search, addeventlistener

With HTML, CSS and JS I've made an expanding search bar, but I don't really know how to close it again.

My HTML code is very simple as I'm just testing how to make a search bar.

```
<div class="search-contain">
    <i class="search fa fa-search" id="search-btn"></i>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="">
</div>
```

The styling isn't really important so here is my JS so far:

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn'); /*From the icon*/
const search = document.getElementById('search'); //From input

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { //Expanding
    search.style.width = '80%';
    search.style.paddingLeft = '60px';
    search.style.cursor = 'text';
    search.focus();

    typewriter();
})

//Effect on the placement of text
var i = 0;
var message = 'Semesterfest';
var speed = 100; //The higher the slower 

function typewriter(){
    if(i < message.length){
        msg = search.getAttribute('placeholder') + message.charAt(i);
        search.setAttribute('placeholder', msg);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
    }

}
```

It's working so far, the bar is expanding when I press the search icon, it focuses on the input field and my typewriter effect is smooth.

But I can't make it close so it's not expanded anymore. It won't go back to the starting state

I'll be honest and say I haven't tried much, I'm very new to JS so I don't have the best idea of what I can do when I run into trouble. I've read somewhere that jQuery might help but I've never used it so I just sticking to plain JS

Comment: How you want it to come back, by clicking a button or just after expanding.

Comment: When it's expanded, after cliking the icon, I want it to colaps back down by clicking the icon one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon was not there so I made a `button` when you click first it will expand and when you will click the second time it will collapse,

```js
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('#search-btn');
const search = document.getElementById('search'); //From input
let index =true ;
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { //Expanding
    index ? search.style.width = '80%' :  search.style.width = '20%' ;
    index ? search.style.paddingLeft='60px' :search.style.paddingLeft = '20px'; 
    search.style.cursor = 'text';
    search.focus();         
    typewriter(); 
    index ? index = false : index = true;
})
var i = 0;
var message = 'Semesterfest';
var speed = 100; 
let msg;
 function typewriter(){ 
    if(i < message.length){
        msg = search.getAttribute('placeholder') + message.charAt(i);
        search.setAttribute('placeholder', msg);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="search-contain">
      <button class="search fa fa-search" id="search-btn">button</button>
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
```

Now you can add more `CSS` or modify the existing one as you want.